# Making code execute in Sync VB.net | WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am designing an application in WPF where if you click on a button it will load that application. Example, you press spotify it will load spotify.

Thing is, sometimes there is delays for when the application (Spotify) opens which is normal! So I am adding a loading section so it will hide the logo, and my loading panel will appear in its place!

Works and looks great but I have an issue! Some reason, the gui wont update with my loading but instead my application loads first and then a few moments after it will update GUI with my loading bar. I want it so as soon as a user presses the button then they will instantly see this loading appear and then will disappear once application has successfully loaded in.

Button code:

```
Dim syncTask As New Task(Of Long)(Function()
                                              MPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden 'Hide Button Info
                                              LoadPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'Show Load
                                              Dim LPro = Process.Start(SpotifyGlobalDir)
                                              Console.WriteLine("Loading App")
                                              LPro.WaitForInputIdle()

                                              Dim ProcessCheck = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify")
                                              Do
                                                  Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                              Loop Until ProcessCheck.Count > 0

                                              Console.WriteLine("App loaded")
                                              ' LoadPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden 'Hide Load
                                              'MPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'Show Button Info
                                              Return True
                                          End Function)
        syncTask.RunSynchronously()
```

I think I might need some multithreading? But if i do that i get errors as I need to invoke the visibility changes which I dont know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `Process.Start` and `Thread.Sleep` on background thread but set the `Visibility` properties of the elements on the UI thread:

```
MPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden 'Hide Button Info
LoadPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'Show Load
Task.Run(Sub()
             Dim LPro = Process.Start(SpotifyGlobalDir)
             Console.WriteLine("Loading App")
             LPro.WaitForInputIdle()

             Dim ProcessCheck = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify")
             Do
                 Thread.Sleep(2000)
             Loop Until ProcessCheck.Count > 0
         End Sub) _
        .ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                          Console.WriteLine("App loaded")
                          LoadPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden 'Hide Load
                          MPanel_Spotify.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'Show Button Info
                      End Sub, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
```

The UI thread cannot both display the controls and sleep at the same time. A single thread can only do one single thing at a time.

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks very much for the help :)